# What is the most lightweight eclipse install for PyDev project?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-installer

I'd like to use eclipse and PyDev as my Python development environment. I have downloaded the eclipse installer (2019-03 version), however this presents options for "Java Developers", "C/C++ Developers", "PHP Developers", etc., with no option for Python developers.

I'm thinking each of the available options may include large amounts of functionality I don't need, leading to a bloated install. So, which is the most stripped-back minimum install that I can install the PyDev plugin over?

Comment: The Eclipse installer provides IDE packages built from software of Eclipse projects, but PyDev is not an Eclipse project. For PyDev see: http://www.pydev.org/download.html#standalone-install

Comment: The absolutely smallest Eclipse install is actually the 'Platform Runtime Binary' on the [Eclipse Project Downloads](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.11-201903070500/) page. But this is extremely minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have tried both solutions. I found the "Platform" install of Eclipse too minimal in that it was not as intuitive as the full install and I couldn't see how to add plugins (Eclipse Marketplace is not available). Therefore, for the best eclipse-like experience, installing Liclipse for PyDev standalone through the link @howlger provided was the best light-weight solution. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer offers IDE packages built from software from Eclipse projects, but PyDev is not an Eclipse project.

- [The PyDev website recommends to use **LiClipse** for a PyDev **standalone installation**](http://www.pydev.org/download.html#standalone-install)
- Alternatively, you can start with the ***Platform Runtime Binary*** [which can be downloaded from the Eclipse project website](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/). The *Eclipse Marketplace Client* (which makes it easier to install additional software) can be installed via *Help > Install New Software...* from the latest Simultaneous Releases update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest).

Comment: The info on how to install the Eclipse Marketplace Client on the Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary, as a route to adding PyDev, is a useful addition.

Comment: @Dave [I'm building my customized Eclipse IDE via Maven myself](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized), but this requires some knowledge about Maven and Eclipse-based development. A lighter solution would be to use a [p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) command line call. But I suspect that both would be over the top for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options for using Eclipse as an IDE for a Python interpreter. It is worth pointing out the following points with respect to PyDev, the plugin that may be used in Eclipse...

1. You can use the latest version of Eclipse. You don't need Eclipse Neon, for example.
2. You need to install a working version of Python, I used `3.8.1`.
3. When opening your new Eclipse workspace be sure to click on the marketplace link so that you can search and install PyDev, the plugin you will be using within Eclipse.
4. Once PyDev is successfully installed, be sure your preferences acknowledge that the interpreter is in fact Python in Eclipse: `Eclipse >> PyDev >> Interpreter - Python`
5. From here you can create and build applications using .py file extension where right clicking your code results in running the selected code.